# How to read json fron facebook using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

my question maybe very simple for you but for me its very hard because I'm new to jquery and json.

This link 
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://iphotogra.ph:4732/Images/ViewPhoto?photo_id=3538

will return

```
{
   "http://iphotogra.ph:4732/Images/ViewPhoto?photo_id=3538": {
      "id": "http://iphotogra.ph:4732/Images/ViewPhoto?photo_id=3538",
      "shares": 6,
      "comments": 2
   }
}
```

My question is, how can I access the shares and comments using jquery.

I tried this

```
 var link = "http://iphotogra.ph:4732/Images/ViewPhoto?photo_id=3538";
 jQuery.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + link, function (data) {
     console.log(data.shares);
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to change `console.log(data.shares);` to `console.log(data[link].shares);` because the `shares` property lies inside an object which is referenced by the `link` variable.

```
var link = "http://iphotogra.ph:4732/Images/ViewPhoto?photo_id=3538";
jQuery.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + link, function (data) {
   console.log("Shares : " +data[link].shares , "Likes :"+data[link].likes  );
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ekuriv/1/edit